# Cannot access Google Ads API using .Net Client Library

Tags: c#, .net, google-ads-api

I am using .net client library to access google ads API using C# .NET.

I have configured 'Installed App' account in following order:

1. Configured Manager Account for Developer Token.
2. Created oAuth credentials using Manager Account and developer console
3. Created test manager account (test Account isn't linked to Ads account).
4. Enabled Ads API from Ads Console.
5. Placed configuration in App.Config

App.Config configuration:

```
    <add key = 'OAuth2Mode' value = 'APPLICATION' />
    <add key = 'OAuth2ClientId' value = 'OAUTH-CLIENT-ID' />
    <add key = 'OAuth2ClientSecret' value = 'SECRET' />
    <add key = 'OAuth2RefreshToken' value = 'REFRESH-TOKEN' />
    <add key="DeveloperToken" value="DEV-TOKEN" />
```

I got refresh token from adwords client-library OAuthTokenGenerator.exe using Test account.

Here is my code to access Ads API:

```
 public static void GetCampaigns(GoogleAdsClient client, long customerId)
 {
      client.Config.LinkedCustomerId = customerId.ToString();
      GoogleAdsServiceClient googleAdsService = client.GetService(Services.V9.GoogleAdsService);

      string query = @"SELECT
                            campaign.id,
                            campaign.name,
                            campaign.network_settings.target_content_network
                        FROM campaign
                        ORDER BY campaign.id";

            try
            {
                // Issue a search request.
                googleAdsService.SearchStream(customerId.ToString(), query,
                    delegate (SearchGoogleAdsStreamResponse resp)
                    {
                        foreach (GoogleAdsRow googleAdsRow in resp.Results)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Campaign with ID {0} and name '{1}' was found.",
                                googleAdsRow.Campaign.Id, googleAdsRow.Campaign.Name);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            catch (GoogleAdsException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure:");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message: {e.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Failure: {e.Failure}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Request ID: {e.RequestId}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

However i am receiving this exception on calling API:

```
 Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated", Detail="Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1643028386.159000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.181.106:443","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1070,"grpc_message":"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","grpc_status":16}")
```

can anyone guide me what am i missing in this configuration?

Comment: You are missing the authentication : https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng how authentication is missing? i have generated OAuth credentials, and credentials are being passed with the request.. do i need to do anything else to authenticate?

Comment: What about the API KEY?

Comment: @jdweng API Key isn't required in case of OAuth credentials i guess

Comment: Read carefully!  The Auth is for client to your app.  The API key is to the google database.